# 99 Haskell Questions #9

Tags: haskell

https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10

regarding the solution to Question 9

```
pack :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]                        -- problem 9
pack [] = []
pack (x:xs) = (x:first) : pack rest
     where
       getReps [] = ([], [])
       getReps (y:ys)
               | y == x = let (f,r) = getReps ys in (y:f, r)
               | otherwise = ([], (y:ys))
       (first,rest) = getReps xs

--input
pack ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a','a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
--output
["aaaa","b","cc","aa","d","eeee"]
```

whats going on here: `(x:first)`, i can see that `rest` is being passed `pack`, but i don't understand the bit before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getReps` is a function specific to each iteration of `pack`, as it closes over the current values of `x` and `xs`.

The first call to `pack "aaaabccaadeeee"` results in a call to `getReps "aaabccaadeeee"`. `getReps` will return `("aaa", "bccaadeeee")`. Effectively, `pack` self splits off the first `'a'` (the value of `x`), and `getReps` separates the rest of the `'a'`s from the value of `xs`. Thus, the final "value" of `pack "aaaabccaadeeee"` is `('a':"aaa") : pack "bccaadeeee"`.

Comment: you didn't mention the bit I'm asking about, i mostly already understand but the very end bit, is what i'm confused about, please say more about `('a':"aaa"):pack "bccaadeeee"`, does the colon mean the same thing? that colon splits head from tail when it's in brackets doesn't it? i don't understand

Comment: Yes, but that's because `:` is a *data constructor*. In a pattern, it is used to identify the head and tail of an existing list, but in the definition of the function, it is used to *create* a list from a given element and another list.

Comment: Since `x == 'a'` and `first == "aaa"`, then `(x:first) == "aaaa"`, which becomes the first element a list that results from calling `pack "bccaadeeee"` to get the rest of the list.